# Angular JS Navigation from Login Page to Dashboard Page

Tags: angularjs

I have a login.html and dashboard.html. Login.html contains the login form and I want users to go to dashboard.html after successful login.

The Problem:
login.html is not a view so we can't use routes to navigate to dashboard.html. But I want to maintain the angular control over both files. 
How can I do that.
Shall I same ng-app on both files.

Currently: I am using:

```
window.location.href='http://sid.dev/dashboard.html';
```

Please guide the best way for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
getLoginDetails().then(function(response,status){           
    // check if successful
    $scope.isLoginSuccessful = true;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="!isLoginSuccessful">
    <!-- Login Form -->
</div>

<div ng-if="isLoginSuccessful">
    <div ng-include src="'dashboard.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the partials <ng-view></ng-view> in dashboard.html work in this case